# try catch block in Matlab

Tags: matlab

So, I am reading hundreds of image files via `imread('D:\pic1\foo.jpg')` and some of them are like `imread('D:\pic2\Thumbs.db')`. After reading I am storing in a database like this, `train(i) = imread('D:\pic1\foo.jpg')`. The problem is with `imread('D:\pic2\Thumbs.db')`, the reading of such files gives error obviously . I wanted to mitigate this problem like this:

```
for i=1:N
  try
    train(i) = imread(link{i})

    %link{i} can be 'D:\pic2\Thumbs.db' or 'D:\pic1\foo.jpg'

  catch 
    disp('Error')
  end
end
```

The issue is in the try block here. There are two things happening one is reading the file another is assigning imread value to `train(i)`. Now, this is important, only on a successful `imread()` should there be an assignment and on a failure there would an error. Matlab takes care of the error via catch block, there isn't a block to take care of the success condition where I can do the assignment, so that I can read and write without much hassle.

I want something like this:

```
j = 0;
for i=1:N

  try:
   imread(links{i})

  if success:
   train(j) = imread(links{i})
   j = j+1;

  if fail:
   error
  end

end
```

I only came up with try and catch while searching Matlab docs, I will really appreciate if there is anything which will help me to write the code succinctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [solution by @gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20737546/232610) is correct, but it can be written a bit more succinctly:

```
ct = 1;
for i=1:N

  try
   train(ct) = imread(links{i});
   ct = ct +1; %# if imread fails, this line is not executed

  catch me
    %# report the problematic image, and the reason for failure
    fprintf('image #%i (%s) cannot be opened: %s\n',i,links{i},me.message)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem with a [`continue`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) statement and a temporary variable like so:

```
for i=1:N
  try
    tempVar = imread(link{i});
  catch 
    disp(['Error reading file ' link{i}]);
    continue
  end
  train(i) = tempVar;
end
```

When `imread` throws an error, control is passed to the `catch` block, which displays a message and then calls `continue` to pass control to the next iteration of the for loop, skipping any later commands. When `imread` is successful, the code after the `try\catch` block is run, assigning the output from `imread` to your variable `train`.

Comment: I think there is no need for putting train(i) = tempVar at the end, it is possible to put it in the try block, the catch block will display the error and go to the next loop without continue.I was hoping for some Matlab 'magic' here, anyhow I will also be satisfied that there is none.

Comment: @whoknows: It looks like I had focused on fixing your first example, while @Jonas focused on fixing the second. They mainly differ in whether you want `train` to *always* be length `N` (mine) or whether you want it to only have length equal to the number of valid images (Jonas'). If Jonas' answer better met your needs, please feel free to give him the check. I won't mind. ;)